# Should I url-encode options in Camel Enpoint URIs

Tags: multithreading, apache-camel

On my current project all the camel endpoints URIs are passed through `org.apache.commons.codec.net.URLCodec.encode()`
The original developers are no longer working in the company and I have no idea why they did this.

Is there any good reason to do this? I haven't seen this anywhere before.

Now the real reason why I ask this. We have a route that (after simplification) looks like this:

```java
    from("direct:start")
      .split(getFilesToProcess()).parallelProcessing().threads(3, 3)
          .pollEnrich("file:///data/inbox?fileName="+encode("${body.fileName}")+"&move="+encode("../.done/${in.header.CamelFileName.substring(0,6)}/${date:now:yyyyMM}/${file:onlyname}"))
          .to("direct:processFile");
```

This code behaves very strangely when encoding the options in the file URI. When multiple files are treated in parallel: the `pollEnrich` component starts to mix up the files that are passed in through `${body.fileName}` or even picking up the same file multiple times.

When I remove the URL-encoding for the options, I never see the pollEnricher picking up the wrong files.
So it looks like the combination of using `pollEnrich()` in a `parallelProcessing()` block with `URLCodec.encode()` causes some kind of unsafe threading issue in the camel source code.

We are using camel version 2.21.5

Comment: It turns out that the concurrency issues were caused by the URLCodec class, which is not thread-safe (at least not in version 1.9 which I was using). However, even with commons-codec-1.14 (threading issue is fixed in 1.11), I still have incorrect files getting picked up if I encode the fileName=${body.fileName} option

Comment: `encode` method is called only once during configure phase. It just build String once and Camel uses that String, so there is no room for unsafe operations. I think your colleague somehow found by double encoding a hacky way to superpass security option `jailStartingDirectory` :-) . By default Apache Camel forbids moving file outsite starting directory. Try to remove all double encoding and add `jailStartingDirectory=false`

Answer (score 0):

See [here in the Camel docs](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/how-do-i-configure-endpoints.html#HowdoIconfigureendpoints-Configuringparametervaluesusingrawvalues)

> When configuring endpoint options using URI syntax, then **the values is by default URI encoded**

When you encode them too, they are double encoded. I think that could be a problem when an encoded character contains characters that are encoded again. I am quite surprised that you don't have any problems because of this.

The default encoding of Camel is also the reason why there is a RAW function to pass values in the original form because the encoding would destroy them (for example passwords).

Comment: It turns out that the expression ${in.header.CamelFileName.substring(0,6)} in the move option doesn't work without (double) encoding.